# pagination with css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I mainly want to show 3 sections and paginate them, in a very simple way, as if it was a tabs situation. 
The principle i need to use is like: if the pagination item has a class active on the first item, then show the first block. I'm stuck on the javascript logic though.

My html:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="first active">1</li>
    <li class="second">2</li>
    <li class="third">3</li>
</ul>
<div class="block first">page 1</div>
<div class="block second">page 2</div>
<div class="block third">page 3</div>
```

and javascript

```
$(".pagination li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});

if ($(".pagination li.first").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".block.first").css("display" , "block");
}

else if ($(".pagination li.second").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".block.second").css("display" , "block");
}
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2e4nd97/1/

the if works, the elseif doesn't. But I'm not sure this is the right way to go. Looks too verbose. Can you help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$(".pagination li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    // hide all .block elements
    $( ".block" ).hide();
    // show .block with the same index as clicked li
    $( ".block" ).eq( $( this ).index() ).show()
});
```

Your `if` statement can be deleted.